# SELECT COUNT(*) Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, count, innodb

Lately I discovered that the most consuming requests in my website are the `SELECT COUNT(*)`
a simply request can take sometimes more than a second

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM post WHERE category regexp '[[:<:]](17|222)[[:>:]]' AND approve=1 AND date < '2014-01-25 19:08:17';
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|  3585 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.49 sec)
```

I'm not sure what's the problem I've indexes for category, approve and date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
FROM post
WHERE category regexp '[[:<:]](17|222)[[:>:]]' AND approve=1 AND
      date < '2014-01-25 19:08:17';
```

It is not a *simple* request because the `regexp` has to run on every row (or every row filtered by the other conditions).

An index on `post(approve, date, category)` might help.  You want one index with the columns listed in that order.

EDIT:

If the values are being stored in a space separated list, you might try this to see if it is faster:

```
WHERE (concat(' ', category, ' ') like '% 17 %' or concat(' ', category, ' ') like '% 222 %') AND
      approve = 1 AND date < '2014-01-25 19:08:17';
```

It is possible that these expressions are faster than the regular expression.

And, finally, if you really do need to search for "words" in a field, then consider a full text index.  I think you might have to tinker with the options in this case so numbers are allowed in the index.

Comment: It helped, but still not as fast as I want it to be.

Comment: @Orio . . . If you are storing multiple category ids in the `category` column, then you have hit one of the reasons why storing lists in fields is discouraged.  If this is a case, you need to restructure your database so you have a separate `post_categories` table with one row per post and per category in that post.